# How do I select a conditional expression stored as a variable value for use in a Proc SQL case expression?

Tags: sql, sas, case

I am using the following case expression to validate values of var1 and assign values to a new variable, var1_val. The dataset response_options_scan contains a column called valid_values, which contains all of the  valid values for var1 transposed from a data dictionary file. The dataset response_options_select contains a column called requirement_status which contains the values "All Records", "Required", or a condition such as "var2 contains xyz" that indicates when var1 is required. I am trying to select requirement_status for use in the 3rd when-condition because this code is used in a macro to validate dozens of variables and the conditions in requirement_status should not be hard coded. However, I am getting different results when hard coding a conditional requirement_status vs using a select statement.

Hard coding works and gives the correct values of var1_val.

```
proc sql noprint;
    create table validate_select_test
    as select *
        ,case when var1 in (select valid_values from response_options_scan where variable="var1") then "var1 valid value"
        when var1="" and (select requirement_status from response_options_select where variable="var1") in ("All Records", "Required") then "var1 invalid value: missing" 
        when var1="" and var2 contains 'XYZ' then "var1 invalid value: missing"
        when var1="" then "var1 valid value: missing"
        else "var1 invalid value"
        end as var1_val format=$100.
    from validate_select;
quit;
```

| var1 | var2 | var1_val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A |  | var1 valid value |
|  | ABC | var1 valid value: missing |
|  | ABC:XYZ | var1 invalid value: missing |

Using a select statement does not. To be clear, the value of requirement_status  in response_options_select where variable="var1" is "var 2 contains 'XYZ'". If var2 does not contain XYZ then records where var1=missing should have a value of "var1 valid value: missing" for var1_val.

```
proc sql noprint;
    create table validate_select_test
    as select *
        ,case when var1 in (select valid_values from response_options_scan where variable="var1") then "var1 valid value"
        when var1="" and (select requirement_status from response_options_select where variable="var1") in ("All Records", "Required") then "var1 invalid value: missing" 
        when var1="" and (select requirement_status from response_options_select where variable="var1") then "var1 invalid value: missing"
        when var1="" then "var1 valid value: missing"
        else "var1 invalid value"
        end as var1_val format=$100.
    from validate_select;
quit;
```

| var1 | var2 | var1_val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A |  | var1 valid value |
|  | ABC | var1 invalid value: missing |
|  | ABC:XYZ | var1 invalid value: missing |

Comment: I think you're hoping that `when var1="" and (select requirement_status from response_options_select where variable="var1") then "var1 invalid value: missing"` will somehow evaluate the condition `var2 contains('xyz')` when that code that is stored in a column requirement_status.  It won't.   Maybe show an example of your validate_select data, response_options_scan, and requirement_status.  Then people can suggest other approaches.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, that is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

SQL cannot dynamically alter the executing statement. You will need to use your control data containing the language snippets to generate source code using them.

Example:

```
data response_options_select ;
  infile datalines length=linelength;
  length variable $32 requirement_status $200;
  input variable& requirement_status& ;
datalines;;;;
var1  expr:var2 contains "XYZ"
var1  expr:var2 contains "pqr"
;;;;

%macro case_gen(control=, var=);

  %local dsid;
  %local variable requirement_status;
  %let dsid = %sysfunc(open(&control(
                              keep=variable requirement_status 
                              where=(variable="&var" and requirement_status like 'expr:%')
                            )
                      ));
  %put %sysfunc(sysmsg());
  %syscall set(dsid);
  ( 0 /* code gen */
  %do %while (%sysfunc(fetch(&dsid))=0);
    or  /* code gen */ %substr(&requirement_status,6)
  %end;
  ) /* code gen */
  %let dsid = %sysfunc(close(&dsid));

%mend;

data have;
  length var1 var2 $200;
  var1 = '' ; var2 = '' ; output;
  var2 = 'ABC'; output;
  var2 = 'ABC:XYZ' ; output;
run;

proc sql;
  create table want as
  select 
    case 
      when missing(var1) and %case_gen(control=response_options_select, var=var1) then 'Invalid: Matched expression in control'
      else 'yada yada yada'
    end as var1_validation
  from have
  ;
quit;
```

when submitted will submit this code in which parts of it was generated code.

```
proc sql;
   create table want as
   select
     case
       when missing(var1) and 
       ( 0 
         or var2 contains "XYZ" 
         or var2 contains "pqr" 
       )
       then 
         'Invalid: Matched an expression in the select control data set'
       else 
         'yada yada yada'
     end as var1_validation
   from have
   ;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Can you help me understand the purpose of the index, rc, and rq_type macro variables. I don't see them referenced anywhere.

Comment: They are left over variables from an earlier version of the code I was writing.  I'll remove them.

Comment: when I run your code I see the following in the log: 
MLOGIC(CASE_GEN):  %DO %WHILE(%sysfunc(fetch(&dsid))=0) loop beginning; condition is TRUE.

When I run the macro with my data it resolves as false every time like so:
 MLOGIC(CASE_GEN):  %DO %WHILE(%sysfunc(fetch(&dsid))=0) loop beginning; condition is FALSE.  Loop will not be executed. 

Do you know what might cause that?

Comment: Only made minor edits for use with my actual data:  

`%macro case_gen(control=, var=);

  %local dsid;
  %local variable requirement_status;
  %let dsid = %sysfunc(open(&control(keep=variable requirement_status where=(variable="&var" and requirement_status like 'if'))));
  %put %sysfunc(sysmsg());
  %syscall set(dsid);
  ( 0 /* code gen */
  %do %while (%sysfunc(fetch(&dsid))=0);
    or  /* code gen */ %substr(&requirement_status,4)
  %end;
  ) /* code gen */
  %let dsid = %sysfunc(close(&dsid));

%mend;`

Comment: The condition `requirement_status like 'if'` is too specific and you want to use `like 'if%'`.  It looks like you are properly grabbing the logical expression source of an if statement by using `%substr(..,4)`.  The where= is case-sensitive, so you might also want to add upcasing to the where= criteria to handle the situations where the control data is not consistent.

Comment: Thanks, using `like 'if%` seemed to resolve it. Can you explain why you added the `0 or` to the code gen section of the macro?

Comment: The clause is comprised of multiple OR sub-expressions.  A sentinel of 0 allows for a clean loop that does not need special case testing (i.e. if this is the first sub-clause then don't codegen and `or`, if second or greater iteration, add an `or` to the code gen) The 0 sentinel is a no-impact sub-clause, and in the loop an unconditional `or` in the codegen is required to create a proper test of the requirement status.  `if%` literal is specifying the SQL like expression wildcard `%` is part of the evaluation